# Trying to enable/disable an input text when a chekbox is unchecked/checked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to enable/diable an input text when a chekbox is checked/unchecked

I have tried this below but it doesn't work..

```
  $('#checkbox').change(function(){


    if($('#name').attr('disabled') == 'true')
      $('#name').attr('disabled', 'false');
    else
      $('#name').attr('disabled', 'true');

  });
```

Any help?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the "disabled" attribute to `true` in both cases.  Try this instead:

```
if($('#name').attr('disabled'))
  $('#name').attr('disabled', false);
else
  $('#name').attr('disabled', true);
```

Or, more simply:

```
 $('#name').attr('disabled', !$('#name').attr('disabled'));
```

The strings you used — "true" and "false" — are both `true` values to JavaScript.  They're non-empty strings, and that's all that matters.  When you use the real constants `true` and `false`, you get what you intended.

The common practice of using "disabled" as the `true` value for the attribute is a silly superstition that has no basis in fact. It does work, of course, because "disabled" is also a non-empty string, and so it's `true`.  You could use `null` for the `false` value if you wanted to, or a numeric zero.

*edit* — fixed the `if` statement as per the helpful comment.  All that's necessary is to check the truthiness of the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, it works but if i use this line instead if($('#name').attr('disabled') == true)

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute should have this value: `disabled` or empty string instead of `true` and `false`.

```
if($('#name').attr('disabled') == 'disabled')
    $('#name').attr('disabled', '');
else
    $('#name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: This is not correct.  All that matters is the truthiness of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if($('#name').attr('disabled'))
    $('#name').removeAttr("disabled");
else
    $('#name').attr("disabled", true);
```

Check if attribute exists and removes it, else adds attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {

    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#name').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From jquery 1.6.1 -> rather use:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").checked)
        $("#name").prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $("#name").prop("disabled", true);

});
```

i.e. use prop instead of attr ( http://api.jquery.com/prop/ )