# JQuery 1.6.2 disable checkbox disables label

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label

We have some existing JavaScript for enabling/disabling a bunch of checkboxes. After upgrading from JQuery 1.4.4 to 1.6.2, it stopped working. Here's what the HTML looks like for each checkbox:

```
<li class="option_row">
  <input id="checked27" class="checkbox normal" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
    <label class="disabled" for="checked27">
      <span>Foo</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

The JavaScript to enable the checkbox is attached to a link (with class "enableCheckboxesLink"):

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkbox');
$('.enableCheckboxesLink').click(function() {
  checkboxes.attr('disabled', '').next().removeClass('disabled');
});
```

In other words, we attach JavaScript to the "enableCheckboxesLink" that finds all checkboxes (that is, all elements with the "checkbox" class) and removes the "disabled" attribute.

When I stop through the code in JQuery 1.6.2, I can see that the var "checkboxes" contains e.g. "input#checked27.checkbox", which is the checkbox above. But when I execute the last line above, it only removes the "disabled" attribute from the *label*, not the checkbox. Why? Is this a bug in JQuery 1.6.2? It worked in JQuery 1.4.4 (that is, the code above enabled both the checkbox and the label).

Comment: I'll assume it was a typo, but you did not close the <input/>

Comment: @Matthew, I think I copied/pasted from a Firebug tree display or something rather than the actual source---that may be why there was no ending slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code which removes the *disabled="disabled"* attribute by using the *attr()* method and setting disabled to *false*.

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkbox');
$('.enableCheckboxesLink').click(function() {
  checkboxes.prop('disabled', false).next().removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference? The [.attr() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) uses `disabled="disabled"`. And nobody has pointed to any documentation on why this would work on JQuery 1.4.4. and not on JQuery 1.6.2.

Comment: The problem is not that you specified disabled="disabled" on the INPUT. It's that you used checkboxes.attr('disabled', '') when you should have used checkboxes.attr('disabled', false) or checkboxes.removeAttr('disabled') to enable the checkbox.  I can't say why it worked in jQuery 1.4.2 but I don't think it was valid syntax.  I would give one of the methods I mentioned above a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, this seemed to be the root of the problem. See also [another question on disabled Boolean values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406509/trying-to-enable-disable-an-input-text-when-a-chekbox-is-unchecked-checked). Josh made a good suggestion about the use of [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) and from the discussion there I can only to guess that older versions of JQuery were more lenient in handling non-Boolean values in the blurring of attributes and properties.

Comment: Glad that fixed it! Yes, in 1.6+ you should use the prop() method for handling properties.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.6 introduced the prop() method, which is recommended for setting the disabled attribute. See [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop#prop2).

So, this should fix your problem:

```
checkboxes.prop('disabled', false).next().removeClass('disabled');
```

This will completely remove the 'disabled' attribute, instead of setting it to an empty string, which still means it is disabled.

Comment: Great suggestion on the use of `.prop()`---thanks for pointing it out. The root issue seems to have been the use of `''` instead of `false` in turning off disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try `removeAttr('disabled')` instead. See http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F

Answer (score 0):

```
checkboxes.attr('disabled', '').next().removeClass('disabled');
```

the reason why the disabled class is being removed is because of next().removeClass('disabled') 
(take the next element and remove class disabled)

I cannot see why the checkboxes aren't disabled why don't you remove:

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkbox');
```

and change:

```
checkboxes.attr('disabled', '').next().removeClass('disabled');
```

to:

```
$('.checkbox').attr('disabled', '').next().removeClass('disabled');
```